# Statefull widget initState() not hit inside a ListView

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview

Trying to integrate a [audioplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) plugin inside a Listview ,This is my structure ,

```
                                         ListView.builder(
                                            cacheExtent: 50.0,
                                            reverse: true,
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                            controller:
                                                _listScrollController,
                                            itemCount: Chats.length,
                                            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                                              print(firebaseUID);
                                              if (Chats[i].data()['IsFile'] !=null && Chats[i].data()['IsFile'] &&
                                                  Chats[i].data()['FileType'] !=null && Chats[i].data()['FileType'] ==
                                                      'audio') {
                                                return AudioSentChat(i: i);
                                              
                                              } else
                                                return Container();
                                            },
                                          );
```

And Audio Sent Chat is a Stateless widget like this ,

```
                                       child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
                                          height: 75,
                                          child: PlayerWidget(
                                              url: Chats[i]
                                                  .data()['FileUrl'],
                                              mode: PlayerMode
                                                  .MEDIA_PLAYER),
                                        ),
```

And the PlayerWidget is a Statefull widget with all the play/pause interactions , here https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/packages/audioplayers/example/lib/player_widget.dart

Now the issue is ,

1. when a new audiofile is recorded and added to the listview (added to firebase) , the ui gets updated but when you play it all the files are duplicates , I checked the data , which is perfect and not duplicates.
2. Now when the screen is scrolled a little the and then files are played it works perfectly without any duplicates.

Observations , the intiState() inside the player_widget is not fired on Listview update .

How can this be handled , also is it a bad idea to put a statefull widget inside a listview.

Answer (score 0):

initState() is a method which is called once when the stateful widget is inserted in the widget tree i.e it's use for one time initialization, what you can do is when updating your listview you call a function that retrieves your data again

Example

```
OnTap: setState((){
  Function ();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use add the `_initAudioPlayer` method in `didUpdateWidget`.

> If the parent widget rebuilds and request that this location in the
> tree update to display a new widget with the same runtimeType and
> Widget.key, the framework will update the widget property of this
> State object to refer to the new widget and then call this method with
> the previous widget as an argument.
>
> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html

So when the parent widget is rebuilt, you can use `didUpdateWidget` to run the `_initAudioPlayer` method again as the `initState` is only called once during the widget's lifecycle.

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initAudioPlayer();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(PlayerWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _initAudioPlayer();
  }
```

Comment: didUpdateWidget is getting hit , but not for the new record , for all the old records , untill user does a Listview lazyload manually the new audio file is not getting binded , ie user has to do a manual scroll , then all works perfectly .Planning to do a small scroll with scrollContrller programatically :(